# Umbraco forms data into CiviCRM

Tags: cms-integration

We're in the process of scoping a web rebuild in umbraco CMS whereby we want to integrate with Civi and would like to know what are the options?

We plan to insert data into the CiviCRM (eg. event sign-up / contacts etc.) but not to update. We're using a C# backend, can you recommend the simplest ways of achieving this (we're currently looking at zapier with http, REST, and MySQL)

Can you advise please?